# Propriedade Split do JS

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo alguns testes com arrays e com funções, no caso eu quero que o programa busque um nome que esta no array nomes. O rotina até funciona , mas o console apresenta um erro no Slip e caso o valor da String nome não for achado, ele não consegue exibir o console.log no final.

O erro que aparece e esse: " Erro: TypeError: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference "

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Buscas com JS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="buscaNome">
    <button onclick="ProcurarNome()">Buscar</button>
    <p id="msg"></p>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    // PROJETO DE LISTA DE CONTATOS COM BUSCA E EXCLUSÃO //

        var nomes = new Array();
        nomes[0] = "Carlos Alberto";
        nomes[1] = "Marcos Gabriel";
            nomes[2] = "Juliana Custodio";
            nomes[3] = "Ana Alice";
            nomes[4] = "Pedro Lucas";

            var contador = 0;

            // para buscar nomes
            function ProcurarNome(){
                        try{
                        var nome1 = document.getElementById('buscaNome').value;
                              if(nome1 == ''){
                                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Digite um nome para Buscar';
                        }

                          for (var i = 0; i <= nomes.length; i++) {
                              var ordem  = nomes[i].split(' '); //vai tranformar o nome em um array//

                                  for(var y = 0; y <= ordem.length; y++){
                                 var pesquisa  = ordem.indexOf(nome1); //vai procura o nome//

                            if(pesquisa != -1){                     
                                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Nome pesquisado: "+nome1+"<br>Nome completo : "+nomes[i];
                                break;
                                  }  
                        }
                      }

                        console.log("O nome : "+nome1+" não esta na lista");
                  }catch(erro){
                              console.log("Erro: "+erro);
                        }  
                  }


    </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando acessar uma posição do array "nomes" que não existe, por isso não é possível fazer o `split`.

Altere os laços de repetição removendo o sinal de igual `=`

```
 for (var i = 0; i < nomes.length; i++) {...}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado Caique